# Deliberately vulnerable Flash applications?

Tags: penetration-test, flash, dvwa

I'm trying to find some deliberately vulnerable Flash applications that I can practice security testing on (in the same vein as applications like the Damn Vulnerable applications).

Ive noticed there are a lot of resources on the net that show how to de-compile SWF applications, or how to exploit Flashvars, but there doesnt seem to be any deliberately vulnerable Flash applications out there that I can use for practice.

Does anyone have any suggestions, aside from writing one myself?

Answer (score 1):

You can use OWASP Flash Security Project. There are plenty of resources for such kind of applications: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Flash_Security_Project

Comment: I was really looking for an application I could set up on my home network and practice breaking into, similar to how (for example) OWASP JuiceBox or Google's Gruyere works. These example apps on the OWASP Flash page seem to be vulnerable content on Live hosts, and I don't think its very ethical to use those as targets for practice.